# Isn't it conflict to run several SSH sessions with same port forwarding?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

If I open

```
ssh -L 8888:localhost:80 myhost
```

several times and open page http://localhost:8888/ on client, then by which of many started SSH sessions data will be transmitted?

**UPDATE**

When I ran second SSH I got a message

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8008
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8888
Could not request local forwarding.
```

this means that forwarding occurs only via first SSH and if I close it, forwarding stops. I.e. I can freely create and destroy session.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Solution for what? There isn't even a problem.

Comment: denial is the most predictable of human responses :)

Comment: There are other predictable effects on a questions and answers site, too. But, of course, you are free to accept those...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you share your SSH connection you’ll avoid this issue. Add something like

```
Host myhost
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
  ControlPersist 2h
```

to your `~/.ssh/config`; this will enable ad-hoc connection sharing, with a two-hour persistence. Then whenever you enable port-forwarding, the forwarded port will remain active as long as the master SSH connection stays open. With the above configuration, that’s two hours after the last SSH connection is closed; you can also drop the `ControlPersist` line to have it closed with the last SSH connection (but then your first `ssh` command won’t actually exit when you disconnect, it will wait for all other SSH connections to close). In both cases, you can force a connection to close by running `ssh -O exit myhost`.

Comment: If I close all ssh connections to the given host, wait 1 hour and then open brand new connection, will counter starts again?

Comment: Yes, the persistence time is measured in idle time (no connections). So any connection resets the timer. See `man ssh_config` for details.